# Organising workflow for custom gem development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I want to add some features to one gem. I've forked this gem on GitHub, add changes and push them. Then I created another rails project and add this gem with GitHub link to my repo. Now I can see changes in this gem work.

Now my workflow is:

1. Change something in the gem
2. Push changes to GitHub
3. Run bundle install in other app
4. Start server
5. Watch changes

Now I want to make my work more intensive, so I need more convenient way to organise my workflow. I want to see changes in gem without pushing to GitHub and so on. How to minimise actions to this:

1. Change something in gem locally
2. Restart rails app
3. See changes in gem work

**Update 1**

Installing gem with 'path' option seems not help. I add  tag to main gem layout, add alert with text. Then I run my main app, and see this alert.
After that I go to the gem folder, change alert text. In main app I do `bundle install` and `bundle update`, restart main app, but the text in alert didn't change

**FINAL**

I try to add alert not to layout, but to js script. Now my changes appear as I want. In previous edit my error was that layout is generated once and doesn't change, while scripts are included and can be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use bundler you can point gems to a local path. In your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'madeup', path: '/path/to/gem'
```

This will allow you to see changes immediately.

It is also worth mentioning that you can point to a GitHub repo as well. Although that won't help you in this instance, it's still useful to know.

```
gem 'madeup', github: 'http://github.com/user/repo', branch: 'my-branch'
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and comment later

Comment: I think you should develop localy as @jordelver already said. If you push to github, don't forget to update your bundle ;-).

Comment: Glad it's working, you will still need to restart the server for certain changes as you've discovered.